# Heroku 500 Error but works after reload

Tags: heroku, flask

I'm currently running an app on heroku with python/flask as the main back-end. I've managed to successfully launch the site on heroku ([Here's the site link](http://outlet-beta.herokuapp.com)). What seems to happen is that when I load the sit in the browser after a certain period of time, I will get an error as follows:

```
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.
```

Essentially I am getting a 500 Error, with the following in the heroku logs:

```
2014-01-11T22:08:01.423860+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/ host=outlet-beta.herokuapp.com fwd="207.38.157.121" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=92ms status=500 bytes=291
```

After I reload the page, the site works fine. I'm not 100% sure how to proceed on this front.

I have the Sentry addon that lets me see what's going on with the errors:

```
OperationalError: (OperationalError) (2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')
```

Sentry has logged this as a trending error which happens pretty often, and is logged each time this internal service error occurs.

I'm running the site with ClearDB and Cloudinary. Is there any chance the mysql server isn't getting connected to quickly enough, and after reload it works? If so, how do I fix it?

Comment: What are the host parameters you're using to access mysql?

Comment: would the host parameter be the cloundinary host server?

Comment: If you're using Flask-SQLAlchemy, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14936644/1949092) may be relevant.

Comment: @DazWorrall I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy, though I am not sure how to implement that fix. I do think it is relevant though, so thanks.

Comment: If you can share some of the application setup code I'll show you how to add that setting to the config.

Comment: `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 20`, perhaps?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flask App returning "MySQL server has gone away" after 60 seconds of idle time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14936319/flask-app-returning-mysql-server-has-gone-away-after-60-seconds-of-idle-time)

Comment: Sorry this took a while, but app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 20 worked like a charm